# How to show data from multiple checkbox in Array? Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a problem with show **checked data** in Array in Angular app. When I click on the checkbox I get a true value, but data not show. Data has null value.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kt2uag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**code:**

component.ts

I use this function:

```
fetchSelectedItems() {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.checkboxesDataList.filter((value, index) => {
      console.log(value.selected);
      return value.selected === true;
    });
  }

  fetchCheckedIDs() {
    this.checkedIDs = [];
    this.checkboxesDataList.forEach((value, index) => {
      if ((value.selected)) {
        this.checkedIDs.push(value.code);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem or error you are facing ?

Comment: `this.checkedIDs.push(value.code);` not show data from value.code what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `fetchCheckedIDs()` just on `ngOnInit(){}`. Call the method in your `fetchSelectedItems()` too:

```js
  fetchSelectedItems() {
    this.fetchCheckedIDs(); //call here
    this.selectedItemsList = this.checkboxesDataList.filter((value, index) => {
      console.log(value.selected);
      return value.selected === true;
    });
  }
```